# Why does refrigerator have the prefix "re"?

Tags: prefixes

Shouldn't it just be frigerator??  What I am specifically looking at is the prefix "re" [to add the meaning "do again", especially to verbs, e.g. rebuild, remarry] when most things you would put in the Refrigerator are room temperature.  I imagine this would even be more so in the past.

Comment: Fresh food isn't cold; it's room temperature

Comment: The re- in English does not mean "do again" in refrigerator!!!!

Comment: If I buy food cold, bring it home in a warm car, and then refrigerate it, I'm making it cold again. Anyway, the earliest form is *to refrigerate*, from the Latin *refrīgerāre* and/or the French *réfrigérer*. Ask the Latins...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the false premise that re-  in refrigerator is an English prefix meaning "do again" .

Comment: I thought your answer was fine, @Josh, its not your fault KDog wasn't interested in hearing it.

Comment: @Josh It's not a false premise.  I think I just found it.  It goes back to the sequence of bathing in your frigidarium.  See reference below in accepted answer.

Comment: @BradC - thanks, but  they'll never admit it. Anyway, it was a question about Latin, not English.

Comment: The question is about the English word.

Comment: Seeing how your question is "why does it say make cold again", and the answer you've accepted says "it means to make cold again", I have to close the question as pointless waste of everyone's time. Are you or are you not interested in knowing why it says make cold *again* even though there is no again? I do not understand. You've accepted an answer that merely repeats your question right back at you and nothing else.

Comment: See [etymonline for refrigeration](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=refrigeration)

Comment: Ack, @RegDwigнt I have written an answer about the English word refrigerator, which was not a pointless waste of time. Questions here are very often not worded perfectly but allowed to remain open.

Comment: The different effects of the prefix re- are listed by [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/re-). Your research will be in vain if you don't realise that re- doesn't always convey the 'again' meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My dictionary does say that Latin *refrigerare* (to make cool) is composed of *re-* (back) and *frigus, frigor* (cold).

Comment: Interesting, but not sure that how the latin word was assembled is relevant, if the entire word *refrigerare* was lifted to English.

Comment: Yes, and it seems to be that it has to do with the sequence of bathing.  The Frigidarium was the first bath entered.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Roman_bathing And then you returned to it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frigidarium  to close your pores.  To make cool again!

Comment: @K Dog You da man.

Comment: @KDog it has more to do with Latin *refigare* (to cool down, to cool again) in the medical or scientific sense. e.g., the necessity of "**re**frigerating"  someone who had a fever - to cool him down/again

Comment: @Clare it could be one of the noun/verb convergences where the pools would be the place to do what you describe.  I would totally buy that.

Comment: This answer not only does not bother to cite *which dictionary* it refers to, but it doesn't say anything about the English word *refrigerator*.

Answer (score 1):

`Re-` in Latin does not always mean "back" or "again".  Sometimes it is just an intensifier.

Look at *request* or *require* or even *refried*.  You aren't doing anything again, just doing it more strongly.

Comment: *Refried* being Spanish and not Latin, but it seems to be the same idea.